# Oracle SQL Question- Error Message ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle

First time using oracle for this type of query, I have to return the conversation rate for a number of initial visits converted to a specific type of appointment. Hoping to show, if a 'specific exam' is not in the dataset then it will return null. If converted, then to return the date of the specific exam.

These all live in the same tables, therefore I left joined the specific exam type (limited by a 'TYPE' in the where clause) to my initial visit (also limited by a 'TYPE' in the where clause). So far it seems to yield results up until  **and ex.ex_date < next.next_date** , which i was using to indicate the the specific type of exam happened after the initial visit.
`Returns ORA-00904: "": invalid identifier`

```
SELECT ex.*,next.next_date FROM

(SELECT tb2.id "ID"
        ,TO_CHAR(tb1.apptdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') "ex_date"

FROM db.VISITTABLE tb1
    LEFT JOIN db.PATIENTABLE tb2
        ON tb1.ptKEY =  tb2.ptKEY

WHERE tb1.appt >= '01-Sep-2022'
    AND tb1.appt < '01-Sep-2023'
    AND tb1.TYPE IN 'InitialVisit'

 )) ex

Left join    
    (SELECT tb2.id "ID"
        ,TO_CHAR(tb1.apptdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') "next_date"

FROM db.VISITTABLE tb1
    LEFT JOIN db.PATIENTABLE tb2
        ON tb1.ptKEY =  tb2.ptKEY


WHERE tb1.TYPE IN 'SpecificExam'
) next

 on ex.ID = next.ID
 and ex.ex_date < next.next_date
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-00904/